# Prove that $I$ is not a principal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

If $R$ is the ring that consist of all sequences of integers $(a_1,a_2,a_3,...)$, with $$(a_1,a_2,...)+(b_1,b_2,...)=(a_1+b_1,a_2+b_2,...)$$ and $$(a_1,a_2,...)(b_1,b_2,...)=(a_1b_1,a_2b_2,...)$$ And $I$ is the subset  of all  $(a_1,a_2,a_3,...)$ of $R$ such that only finitely many $a_j$ are diferent from $0$ (With $(0,0,...)\in I$). I need to show that $I$ is not a principal ideal.

So far I have been able to prove that indeed $R$ is a ring; in particular, this ring is commutative and it has identity, and that $I$ is an ideal, which is simple. But my problem is in showing that $I$ is not a principal ideal.

I think one way to show this is assuming that $I$ is a principal ideal, then there exists $(a_1,a_2,a_3,...)\in R$ such that $((a_1,a_2,a_3,...))=I$. But I could not find the contradiction in this step. Can you help me please?

Comment: Hint: $a_n=0$ for some $n$. So what can you say of the $n$-th coordinate of any element in $Ra$?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $\mathbf{a}=(a_1,a_2, \ldots)$ is a generator, then there exists a $k$ such that $a_n=0$ for all $n \geq k$. Now consider an element in $I$ such that $(0,0, \ldots ,\underbrace{1}_{k^{\text{th}}}, 0,0,\ldots)$, i.e having the only non-zero entry $1$ at the $k-$th place. Can it be generated by $\mathbf{a}$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a$ is a candidate to generate the ideal $I$ and is $0$ at the $n$-th component. Then the ideal generated by $a$ will not contain $e_n$, the element of $I$ which has $1$ at the $n$-th component and zero elsewhere.

Comment: I think I follow you. The general idea is: The element $a$ always leave out elements that should be in $I$ (?)

Comment: @Hopmaths Correct.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\b}{\mathbf}$The other answers have already given an argument to show that it is not principal. However, one can show that it is not even *finitely generated*, i.e., you cannot write $I = (\b a_1, \ldots, \b a_n)$ for any choice of finitely many elements $\b a_1, \ldots, \b a_n \in I$. (I'm using boldface to indicate that we are talking about sequences.)

Indeed, let $\b a_1, \ldots, \b a_n \in I$ be arbitrary. We show that there exists an element in $I$ which is not in the ideal $(\b a_1, \ldots, \b a_n)$.

> The idea is the following: Given any finite number of sequences in $I$, you can find a common $N \in \Bbb N$ such that all those sequences are $0$ after position $N$. On the other hand, you can cook up another element in $I$ which has a $1$ after position $N$.

By definition of $I$, there exist integers $k_1, \ldots, k_n \geqslant 1$ such $\b a_1$ has $0$s after the $k_1$-th position, $\b a_2$ has $0$s after the $k_2$-th position, and so on. (In general, $\b a_i$ has $0$s after the $k_i$-th position for all $1 \leqslant i \leqslant n$.)

Now, pick $N = \max\{k_1, \ldots, k_n\}$. Thus, we have that each $\b a_i$ has $0$s after the $N$-th position. Now, consider the new element $$\b e_{N + 1} := (0, \ldots, 0, 1, 0, \ldots)$$
where the $1$ is in the $(N + 1)$-th position. Clearly, $\b e_{N + 1} \in I$ and $\b e_{N + 1} \notin (\b a_1, \ldots, \b a_n)$.

Comment: A small question. Is the ideal that is not generated by a single element also a principal ideal?

Comment: @Hopmaths: No. By definition, a principal ideal is one which _can_ be generated by a single element. (Note the "can". For example, $I = (4, 6) \subset \Bbb Z$ is a principal ideal since it is also equal to $(2)$. On the other hand $(2, X) \subset \Bbb Z[X]$ is not a principal ideal because it **cannot** be written as $(f(X))$. This requires a proof.)